# Update SQL variable when recordset is empty

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

We have a loop in SQL Server 2005 that loops around on a table getting each items parent until it gets to the top of the tree:

```
DECLARE @T Table
(
  ItemID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  AncestorID INT NULL 
)
```

Which has data like this:

```
ItemID | AncestorID
  1          2
  2          3
  3          4
  4          NULL
```

We have a loop that basically does this:

```
DECLARE @AncestorID INT
SELECT @AncestorID = 1
WHILE (@AncestorID IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN   
  --Do some work   
  SELECT @AncestorID = T.AncestorID   
  FROM @T t  
  WHERE T.ItemID = @AncestorID

  print @AncestorID
END
```

(Yes I know SQL is set based, and this is processing row by row, the "Do some work" needs to be done line by line for a reason).

This has always worked fine until today when we ended up in an endless loop. Turns out the cause was some wrong data:

```
ItemID | AncestorID
  1          2
  2          3

  4          NULL
```

`ItemID` 3 was deleted. The loop now never ends because `AncestorID` is never `NULL` - it stays at 3.

Is there anyway to rewrite the select statement to make `@AncestorID` null if the `SELECT` query returns 0 rows, or do I need to have a separate `SELECT` statement to count the records and some `IF ELSE` type logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there anyway to rewrite the select statement to make @AncestorID
>   null if the SELECT query returns 0 rows,

You can use an aggregate on `T.AncestorID`.

```
SELECT @AncestorID = min(T.AncestorID)   
FROM @T t  
WHERE T.ItemID = @AncestorID
```

Comment: Thanks @Mikael. This was the only answer that didn't involve a second select or a check which is what I was looking to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

You could use another variable, e.g. `@PreviousAncestorId`, to hold the previous value and reset `@AncestorId` to `NULL` before the query.

You could check `@@RowCount` after the query to see if a row was found.

The code will still have issues dealing with cycles of arbitrary length within the data, e.g. a row where both values are the same.  You would need to keep track of the visited rows in order to detect cycles.  A simple reality check would be to count the number of iterations of the loop and check it against the number of rows.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Break`

e.g.

```
WHILE (@AncestorID IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN 

  SELECT T.AncestorID INTO #TEMP 
  FROM @T t WHERE T.ItemID = @AncestorID  

  IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TEMP) = 0) BREAK;

  SELECT @AncestorID=T.AncestorID   
  FROM #TEMP  t  

  print @AncestorID

  DROP TABLE #TEMP

END
```